# Logging into eBay Using VB Web Browser

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to login to eBay through the web browser module in vb but I am struggling to find a way to fill in the boxes by using the click of a button. I have tried this by using the GetElementById as follows:

```
            If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "EQP") Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("1560960309").InnerText = "username"  ' Username
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("1605523682").InnerText = "password"        ' Password
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sgnBt").InvokeMember("click")          ' Click Login Button
```

This code doesn't do anything at all but has worked using other websites, before the eBay ID's used to be simple and I am now finding that these IDs seems to change in each session.

Any help would be great.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cant do this like you can on other websites as Ebay is trying to put a block on all ways of phishing.
 However Ebay does have an API for .NET that you should be able to use and in the long run it will look and feel much better.
 Here is the link : https://go.developer.ebay.com/netsdk 
Hopefully this leads you in the right direction.
Good Luck!

Comment: I think you mean scraping, not phishing.  But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: i thought phishing, because anyone could make a program and send it off to look like ebay and even feel like ebay???

Comment: Could be. I guess it's hard to tell exactly which reason motivates them.  The heart of the matter is that they are trying to prevent automated use of their website (in favor of API for that purpose, which makes sense).  Maybe putting it that way would be less presumptive.